# My PHP mail() Won't work

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, server, smtp

So I've used POSTFIX on an ubuntu laptop with apache2 
and port forwarded the common SMTP ports and the php script worked but now it's not for some reason. I worked flawlessly then suddenly quite which is really weird

HERE'S THE CODE:

```
     $to = 'akaco@tutanota.com';
 $subject = 'Servers4Keys';
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject,
   "<html>
      <body>
        <h3 style='color: red;'>Customers Name: $name</h3></br>
        <h3>Ip: $ip</h3></br>
        <h3>Customers E-mail: $email</h3></br>
        <h3>Chosen Payment Plan: $plan</h3></br>
        <h3>Linux Distro: $distro</h3></br>
        <h3>Payment Type: $paymenttype</h3></br>
        <h3> Add 50 slots: $slots</h3></br>
        <h3>$servers</h3></br><br><br>
        <h3>$message</h3>
      </body>
   </html>",
   $headers);
```

Comment: any errors in the error logs?

Comment: Please post the error messages.